# Ajax insert in database return 404 error in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to insert simple form in database trough ajax without refreshing the page in Wordpress.

For some reason when I click on submit button I've got that the page isn't found - 404 error.

I have added this to my theme `function.php`

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_ajax_scripts'); 
function my_ajax_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/formSubmit.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'myscript', 'myajax', array( 'ajaxurl' =>   admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

function applyform(){
        global $wpdb;
        $table = jobs;
        $data = array(
            'name' => $_POST['name'],
            'email'    => $_POST['email'],
            'form_id'    => $_POST['form_id']
        );
        $format = array(
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s'
        );
        $success=$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format );
        if($success){
            //wp_redirect( site_url('/') );
            die;
        }
}

//ADD THE AJAX HOOKS IN WORDPRESS
add_action('wp_ajax_applyform', 'applyform');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_applyform', 'applyform');
```

Then I have this in the `formSubmit.js`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 

    $('#submit').submit(function(e){ // Updated            

        var applicantform = $(this).serialize(); // serializing the form data

        e.preventDefault();

        //ajax call
        $.ajax({
            type:   'POST', 
            action: 'applyform', 
            url:    myscript.ajaxurl, // the functional url     
            data:   myscript.applyform, // all the data of the form (serialized)

            // Displaying succes message
            success: function( data ){
                $('#result').html( 'Success : '.data );
                // for debugging purpose in browser js console
                console.log(data);
            },

            // Displaying error message     
            error: function( error ){
                $('#result').html( 'Error! : '. error );
                // for debugging purpose in browser js console
                console.log(error);
            }               
        });
    });
});
```

And this is the form in modal window on the page

```
<form method="post" id="applicantform">
     <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nmae" />
     <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
     <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

I don't see anything in the console log. Not `console.log(data)` nor `console.log(error)`. On form submit it goes straight to not found page.

Comment: applicantform or applyform is your serialized data?

Comment: I'm not sure. For what I understand from some posts the ajax action should match the function name in this case `applyform` that's why I've made it like this. But I believe it should be `applicantform` as I have this in JS `var applicantform = $(this).serialize();`

Comment: I've also tried with `applyform` on all 3 places - same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check your ajax call structure!
To make this ajax call work, you have to send your action within "data" object. The form data you've collected and dumped into a variable "applicantform" is missing also.

**Update**
it looks like you are confusing your assigned ajax url! Instead of using `myscript.ajaxurl` you have to use `myajax.ajaxurl`

### Ajax Call

```
 //ajax call
        $.ajax({
            type:   'POST', 
            url:    myajax.ajaxurl, // ajax url you assigned!   
            data: {
                 action: 'applyform',   // send your action within data 
                 formdata: applicantform, // all the data of the form (serialized)
            },

            // Displaying succes message
            success: function( data ){
                $('#result').html( 'Success : '.data );
                // for debugging purpose in browser js console
                console.log(data);
            },

            // Displaying error message     
            error: function( error ){
                $('#result').html( 'Error! : '. error );
                // for debugging purpose in browser js console
                console.log(error);
            }               
        });
```

### Javascript including ajax

Your form id  -> applicantform doesn't match the selector, so you have to change your selector like this!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 

    $('#submit_form').click(function(e){        

        var applyformData = $('#applicantform').serialize(); // serializing the form data

        e.preventDefault();

        //ajax call
        $.ajax({
            type:   'POST', 
            url:    myajax.ajaxurl, // ajax url you assigned!   
            data: {
                 action: 'applyform',   // send your action within data 
                 formdata: applyformData, // all the data of the form (serialized)
            },

            // Displaying succes message
            success: function( data ){
              window.location.replace("https://example.org");
            },

            // Displaying error message     
            error: function( request ){
                $('#result').html( 'Error! : '. error );
                // for debugging purpose in browser js console
                console.log(request); 
            }               
        });
    });
});
```

### Serverside PHP

since you've serialized your data you have to use parse_str on php side.
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_parse_str.asp

```
function applyform(){
        global $wpdb;

        if (!check_ajax_referer( 'my_nonce' )){
        wp_die();
        }

        $table = jobs;

    // serialized data from ajax
        $formdata = $_POST['formdata'];

   // use parse_str to unserialize
        parse_str($formdata, $formdata_array);

   // accessing your data like...
        $data = array(
            'name' => $formdata_array['name'],
            'email' => $formdata_array['email'],
            'form_id' => $formdata_array['form_id']
        );

        $format = array(
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s'
        );
        $success=$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format );
        if($success){
        // do something
            die();
        }
die();
}
```

### Security

For security reasons you should consider using `wp_nonce_field('my_nonce');`.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field

Using the following snippet inside your form creates a security nonce you have to verify serverside.

```
<form method="post" id="applicantform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'my_nonce' ); ?>
</form>
<button type="button" id="submit_form">Send</button>
```

Serverside inside your function `applyform` just check like...

```
if (!check_ajax_referer( 'my_nonce' )){
wp_die();
}
```

Comment: Still got 404 page

Comment: ok, please try url: ajaxurl, instead of using url: myscript.ajaxurl, or check if myscript.ajaxurl is accessible!

Comment: I've lost the track of changes. Also in the serverside part from where it come `$_POST['formdata']` do I need to change the name of the form to `formdata`?

Comment: Also, how do I check if `myscript.ajaxurl` is accessible

Comment: @Jordan Serverside $_POST is fetching data from the ajax.data object, so if you assign formdata: applicantform, to the data object its accessible on serverside through $_POST['formdata']. You're fine so far...

Comment: just check if its not undefined in console -> console.log(myscript.ajaxurl);

Comment: Yes, but if I have multiple `$name = $formdata_array['name']; $email = $formdata_array['email']; $somethingelse = $formdata_array['somethingelse'];` how will they go bellow in `$format = array(...`

Comment: `console.log(myscript.ajaxurl);` nothing shows on this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192220/discussion-between-click-here-and-jordan).

Comment: Thank you again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead. You're not serializing the form data by targeting the submit.

```
$('#applicantform').submit(function(e){        

    var applyformData = $(this).serialize(); // serializing the form data

    e.preventDefault();

    //ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type:   'POST', 
        url:    myajax.ajaxurl, // the functional url     
        data:   {
            data: applyformData, // all the data of the form (serialized)
            action: 'applyform',
          } 

        // Displaying succes message
        success: function( data ){
            $('#result').html( 'Success : '.data );
            // for debugging purpose in browser js console
            console.log(data);
        },

        // Displaying error message     
        error: function( error ){
            $('#result').html( 'Error! : '. error );
            // for debugging purpose in browser js console
            console.log(error);
        }               
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but still same. In the network tab of the console I see the URL on which I'm currently as 404

Comment: The problem is action needs to be in the data array. I can write it out in like 20 minutes... I'm on Mobile

Comment: I would be glad if you can help on this because it seems like that I can't figured it out

Comment: The problem also seems to be that the form is in modal window. When I put the input fields without modal they are saved in database

Comment: Let me try now and see

Comment: I'm sorry but doesn't seems to work. Throw 404 every time the modal form is submitted.